# Generic Views attributes?

Tags: django

lately I've been learning GCBVs and they are definetly very handy. My big problem is, that I do have a book with all the attributes that I can set. But how can I figure out the attributes that have to be set or can be set without the book (they are spread among a lot of pages and do not cover all the attributes? There are concentions for template_names, context etc.? The source code is very cryptic because there is a lot of multiple inheritance etc.

How do you guys keep track of the GCBVs?

Comment: There is not enough context to answer or understand this question.  Do you want to explain this line `How do you guys keep track of the GCBVs?`

Comment: Sure. Take this for example. If I make a ArchiveIndexView, there are the attributes "allow_empty", "allow_future" ... and many more. All of the different GCBV have many different attributes. I'm am very overwhelmed by the shere amount of the attributes that exist. So I thought there must be a way to keep track of that kind of attributes there are. Do people just memorize what attributes have to be set in a GCBV or do they look in the Django source code? Or is there another way?

Comment: https://ccbv.co.uk has a full list of attributes for every view.